# How to publish a profile to IIS with credentials from command line?

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.2 web project and I want to publish it to an IIS on a different server from the command line.

To that end, I created Publish Profile in my project (Properties/PublishProfiles/myProfile.pubxml).  For username/password, I entered credentials that allow me to publish to that server.  And I selected to save the password. The password is encrypted and saved to myProfile.pubxml.user  I can now easily publish from Visual Studio without having to enter username/password.

Most answers seem to coalesce on an idea of running the following command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release /p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\myProfile.pubxml
```

The problem is that this command seems to ignore the username/password resulting in `MSDEPLOY : error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN. The remote server returned an error : (401) Unauthorized.`

Is there a way to make `dotnet publish` pick up the username/password so that the publish operation could succeed?

Comment: USER_NOT_ADMIN  try running the cmd prompt as admin before trying the command. There's a chance some rpc magic is involved, and might need local admin to use. Blind guessing :)

Comment: @Davesoft That was the first thing I tried.  Unfortunately, I can't even open a command prompt window with those credentials - corp policy has that user locked down.

Comment: @AngryHacker have you found a solution for this meanwhile?

Comment: @marcobirchler No, ended up using Jenkins/Octopus for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run msdeploy directly? I was also trying to get it work with dotnet publish but without any luck. Finally I got the solution by just running msdeploy like this:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -setParam:'IIS Web Application Name'='my.website.com' -source:package="PathToPackage.zip" -dest:auto,computerName='https://my.website.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=my.website.com',username=YourUsername,password=YourPW,AuthType='Basic' -allowUntrusted=true
```

This is definitely working without using admin rights on the target environment.